# Can't change orientation to portrait, mobile air apps

Tags: mobile, air, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook

I am developing a Blackberry PlayBook application using Flash Builder 4.6 on a Windows 7, x64 machine. I have installed the Blackberry SDK and generally can test my application with one catch - Rotate Left and Rotate Right options from the menu are grayed out. I don't have the actual tablet (and purchasing one is not a solution) so there is absolutely no way for me to test how the app behaves in the Portrait mode.

Perhaps the problem is the fact that my resolution is 1280x800 without any way to make it bigger (I had expected I'd be able to do this and would just activate the peculiar desktop scrolling mechanism). Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the Playbook emulator in VMWare Player (I use Win 7, 64bit too) - by pulling its black corner with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can check portrait as well as landscape mode both in VMWare simulator. 
Playbook OS is designed in that manner to support development on both resolutions , if you have 1280 x 800 resolution you can access right most part by using scroll bar in Vmware tool. 
BB Playbook os is designed with some predefined features. like in bottom if you use gesture from left most bottom to right , it will open virtual keyboard , & if you will do the same from right most bottom to left , just like swipe down event . it will change the orientation to landscape to portrait or vice versa.